# Hash designed for threads, to be dumped in YAML format

Tags: multithreading, perl

Trying to dump the nested hash map with shared references, in YAML file. Perl code is here. The hash is actually made thread friendly,

```
use v5.18;
use YAML::XS;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Data::Dumper;

my $href1 = shared_clone({
    anotherRef => shared_clone({})
});

$href1->{anotherRef}{test} =  &share({});

print Dumper $href1;

my $path = "./test.yaml";

open  TAG_YAML, '>', $path;
print TAG_YAML Dump($href1);
close TAG_YAML;


1;
```

and in the end, I am trying to dump out the flow, it is showing the reference as mentioned below

```
% ./ref-of-refs.pl ; cat test.yaml
---
anotherRef: HASH(0x21897a0)
```

Is there any option to dump the full hash into YAML format in test.yaml file. ?

Comment: According to [the source](https://metacpan.org/source/JDHEDDEN/threads-shared-1.59/shared.xs#L19) the shared variables are implemented using some sort of magic. My guess is that due to this magic `YAML::XS::Dump()` does not recognize it as a hash ref, hence falls back to output the stringification `HASH(0x21897a0)` instead of the real hash..

Comment: Added [bug report](https://github.com/ingydotnet/yaml-libyaml-pm/issues/100)

Comment: I made a [PR with a fix](https://github.com/ingydotnet/yaml-libyaml-pm/pull/101)

Comment: This is now fixed in [v0.83](https://metacpan.org/release/TINITA/YAML-LibYAML-0.83)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the XS magic that [threads::shared](https://metacpan.org/pod/threads::shared) uses confuses `YAML::XS::Dump()` (since it also uses XS to traverse the hashref). I would suggest you try the pure Perl module [YAML](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML) instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $href1 = shared_clone({
    anotherRef => shared_clone({})
});
$href1->{anotherRef}{test} = shared_clone({});
print Dump($href1);
```

**Output**:

```
---
anotherRef:
  test: {}
```

Comment: A quick look at the source code does show missing calls to `SvGETMAGIC`.

Comment: You could also use [YAML::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::PP) or [YAML::PP::LibYAML](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::PP::LibYAML). YAML.pm is old and buggy.